# 2018 Survey Data Set links to 2017 Survey Data Set

Tags: bug, status-completed, survey-2018

Steps to reproduce:

1. visit https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey
2. click "Download Full Data Set (CSV)" for 2018

Comment: Both link to `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B6ZlG_Eygdj-c1kzcmUxN05VUXM`

Comment: Fixed, thanks for the report!